# Background Processing vs Message Queueing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, message-queue

One should I use one over the other in my Rails app?

Thanks

Comment: This question is *really* lacking in substance. Please explain what you want to do with either of these two things and you will get a *much* better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is usually background processing triggered by a simple rake command.